# How to invert a matrix

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, equation-solving, linear-equation

I need to solve a system of n-linear equations with n-unknown variables in C++ using the gaussian method of elimnation. Any hints how to achieve that? I'll be probably using rand(); for the amount of n, since  isn't available, because C++11 I can't use.

Comment: There is this cool new tool out called, "google." Give it a try.  Seriously, SO is not the correct forum for these types of questions.  I found [this link](http://ww2.odu.edu/~agodunov/teaching/notes/Nm06_matrix2a.pdf) in 2 seconds

Comment: The technique of Gaussian elimination has been known for centuries, so it really shouldn't require "hints." Just look it up. Which specific part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Google "gaussian elimination". First link is the Wikipedia article, which describes the process and provides an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to solve a linear system

AX=B

you need to invert a matrix A, which results in A^(-1) and multiply A^(-1) * B to obtain X.
This is the example code to invert non-singular matrix using Gauss - Jordan elimination algorithm (complexity is O(n^3)):

[matrix inversion using Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://github.com/cf16/examples/blob/master/cppapp_matrix_invertion_0/main.cpp)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Excuse my ignorance, but since I now got this, could you tell me what else I should implement to solve my problem?

Comment: you know your matrix A, right? then you also know A^(-1). so now you just need to multiply this by B and this is your point of interest

Comment: My matrix A is the variables before the variables in the system, right? The matrix B is the variables of the "answer" of those equations?

Comment: yes, i.e.  if: 1x+2y=3, 4x+5y=6, then A 1st row is 1 2 , 2nd row 4 5, B 1st row is 3 , 2nd row 6

Comment: So, to find the value of the variables, I have to invert the matrix A, and multiply it to B, that's all I have to do?

Comment: And the matrix X will have the values of the variables? :)

Comment: what variables? only variables in AX=B is matrix X. and X=A^(-1)*B

Comment: I meant the unknown ones is X. (The one we have to find)

Comment: @user3182683 X=A^(-1)*B, A,B are known, thus A^(-1) is known too